Controls - seeing if a discrete time system can arrive from a certain input to a certain output
Given a system:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 7 & -3 \\ 18 & -8 \end{pmatrix} \quad B = \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\-6\end{pmatrix} \quad C = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \quad D =0$$
I need to see if for \$x[0] = [1, -1]^T\$ I can get to \$x[10] = [2, -2]^T\$ for any given input \$u\$
I proved the system isn't controllable by showing \$|\mathbb{C}|=0\$. I know I need to check individually, but I don't know how to proceed after placing the constants in the formula - specifically, what to do with the sum. In the answers they simplify it to a constant times \$[1,3]\$ but I don't understand how.
$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} = A^{10}x[0] + \sum_{j=1}^9 A^{k-1-j}Bu[j]$$

Please show an attempt at a solution

I can show you the controllability matrix, is that what you want me to show?

Beyond substituting it into the controllability matrix, and showing its determinant is 0, I didn't really have much to do - since I don't know how to simplify the sum as the solutions had - that's what I'm asking... and subbing in A^10 is just inputting it into the calculator.

I showed the thought process that lead me to where I'm stuck
